# How to update JWT Identity in flask?

Tags: flask, jwt

I am trying to create an update account view, when the user clicks update I am refreshing the token, and getting the jwt identity.

However the jwt identity is not changing, the user remains the same as before the update. The db is updating however the jwt identity is not.

So how can I update the identity? If all I have is current jwt token and refresh token.

Here are my routes

```
@app.route('/current-user', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def get_current_user():
    # Access the identity of the current user with get_jwt_identity
    try:
        current_user = get_jwt_identity()
        if current_user:
            return Response(json.dumps({"logged_in_as":current_user}), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        else:
            return Response(json.dumps({"error":"Couldn't get user details"}), status=404, mimetype='application/json')
    except:
        return Response(json.dumps({"error":"Something went wrong"}), status=400, mimetype='application/json')

@app.route('/refresh', methods=['POST'])
@jwt_refresh_token_required
def refresh():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    new_token = create_access_token(identity=current_user)
    ret = {'access_token': new_token,"logged_in_as":current_user}
    return Response(json.dumps(ret), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Show your token generation method, you are using the current JWT or you are decoding the token and retrieve the userId to generate a new token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT identity is stored entirely in the token, it does not fetch that information from the database, so any updates in the database will not be reflected until a new JWT is created.

It looks like you are using flask-jwt-extended. Here is how you could load the user from the database in every request using that extension: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/complex_objects_from_token/

Comment: Does using loader call back remove the need to specify an identity when I create the tokens?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you would have no way of knowing what user that token maps to. You could use the user id as the identity for example, then use that to load your users from the database for example